# ',' expected. visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html

```
function checkWin(board, player){
    let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) => 
       (e === player)) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);
            let gameWon = null;
            for (let [index,win] of winCombos.entries()){
```

line three of code comes back with Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: you have extra closing bracket after e===player, which ends the reduce method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) => 
       (e === player)) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);
```

you need

```
let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) => 
       (e === player) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);
```

Comment: Never mind I see it

Comment: Did thank you so much this is my first stack overflow question and your quick answer means the world to me thanks

Comment: @user8430682 you are welcome. The problem was that you have closed a parantheses which was never opened.